# How to add a genitive phrase to Vim spellchecker?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

How can I make Vim's internal spellchecker ignore the genitive form of phrases added to a spellfile?

For example, how can I make the spellchecker ignore "Nicolai's" when "Nicolai" has already been added to the spellfile (without having to add "Nicolai's" to it as well)?

Comment: Which spellchecker are you using? ispell? myspell? aspell? If you don't know, check the output of `dpkg -l | grep -E "^ii.*spell"`.

Comment: I'm using Vim's internal spellchecker. Does Vim rely on an external one?

Comment: I'm 90% sure that _all_ installed programs use the same one. You're probably using myspell.  Not sure this is relevant by the way, but it might be and the more information you give, the likelier it is you'll get a good answer.

Comment: Both `aspell` and `ispell` are installed, and both have the same version: 0.60.7.